# Parse underscore named attribute from response's wrapper

Tags: apex, api, json, deserialize

I'm receiving some JSON from an API. I created a Wrapper like this:

```
public class Wrapper{

    public class cA{

        List<cB> recordsB;

        public class cB{
            cC recordC;

            public class cC{
                String _some_id; // <--- Here I'm getting the error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, when I call it to my HTTP future class, I try to parse it with:
`Wrapper.cA dataResponse = (Wrapper.cA)JSON.deserialize(input, Wrapper.cA.class);`

And I get the error

> "Invalid character in identifier".

Thing is that **I cannot change the name of the comming field _some_id**.
Can anybody tell me how could I parse this child class in order to receive the name as it is?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: See referenced Q&A. While a slightly different root cause, the workaround still applies in your case. As an alternative, you can deserialize via another method. See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302034/how-do-i-get-started-working-with-json-in-apex for suggestions.

Comment: Hello! I cannot use replaceAll or any other Pattern, because the file I'm getting is too long and I get a "Regex too complicated" error.
But the second URL with all the examples gave me the idea to try out the JSON.deserializeUntyped, and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, I came up with this solution:

- First, I remodelled the Wrapper class like this:

```
public class Wrapper{

    List<cA> recordsA;

    public class cA{
        cB recordB;

        public class cB{
            String _some_id; // <--- Here I'm getting the error
        }

    }
    
}
```

- After that, I used **JSON.deserializeUntyped** to control the data:

```
Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(responseBody);
Wrapper dto;
List<cA> wrappers;

if(result.containsKey('recordsA')){
    wrappers = new List<cA> ();
    
    List<Object> jsonList = (List<Object>)result.get('recordsA');
    for(Object o : (List<Object>)jsonList){
        cA recordA = new cA();
        Map<String, Object> w = (Map<String, Object>)o;
            

        if(w.containsKey('___'))    recordA.___ = String.valueOf((Integer)(w.get('___'))); // <-- use as many times as you need for attributes in cA class

        if(w.containsKey('recordB')){
            cB recordB = new cB();
            Map<String, Object> pm = (Map<String, Object>)w.get('recordB');
                
            if(pm.containsKey('___'))   recordB.___ = (String)(pm.get('___'));  // <-- use as many times as you need for attributes in cB class
                
            recordA.recordB = recordB;
        }
        recordsA.add(recordA);
    }
}
```

Two links that helped me a lot:

- [How do I get started working with JSON in Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302034/how-do-i-get-started-working-with-json-in-apex) (thanks  @identigral for the link)
- [JSON.deserializeUntyped() not parsing the whole JSON](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34766/json-deserializeuntyped-not-parsing-the-whole-json)

Answer (score 1):

The Naming Convention for Variables/Attributes in Apex can't have any special character in the beginning.
So, As `identigral` mentioned in the comment, You can either use `JSONParser` to get the values from the JSON body or an easier approach would be to simply replace the attribute from the JSON itself.

```
Wrapper.cA dataResponse = (Wrapper.cA)JSON.deserialize(input.replaceAll('\\_some_id','someId), Wrapper.cA.class);
```

then change the attribute name from your Wrapper class.

```
public class Wrapper{

    public class cA{

        List<cB> recordsB;

        public class cB{
            cC recordC;

            public class cC{
                String someId; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Another approach:** Or if you want to implement [JSONParser](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_JsonParser.htm),

```
JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(input);
      while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
        if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
          String fieldName = parser.getText();
          parser.nextToken();
          if (fieldName == '_some_id') {
            attributeValue = parser.getText(); //you'll get value of the attribute from JSON here...
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Since I cannot use replaceAll, because I'll get a "Regex too complicated" error message (because the volume data I'm handling is too big), I've comed up with this solution that worked for me: